# Can we achieve this if yes then what will the SQL query for same

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table having the following type of data:

```
+---------+------+--------+
| market  | type | amount |
+---------+------+--------+
| LTCBTC  | SELL |   0.15 |
| XMRBTC  | BUY  |  0.005 |
| DASHBTC | BUY  |  0.002 |
| ADABTC  | BUY  |      7 |
| IOTABTC | BUY  |      1 |
| LTCBTC  | BUY  |   0.17 |
| XRPBTC  | BUY  |     12 |
| ETHBTC  | BUY  |   0.03 |
| BCCBTC  | BUY  |  0.005 |
| ETHBTC  | SELL |  0.124 |
| LTCBTC  | BUY  |   0.02 |
| XMRBTC  | BUY  |  0.004 |
| DASHBTC | BUY  |  0.002 |
| ADABTC  | BUY  |      6 |
| IOTABTC | BUY  |      1 |
| XRPBTC  | BUY  |     10 |
| BCCBTC  | BUY  |  0.004 |
| ETHBTC  | BUY  |  0.025 |
| XMRBTC  | BUY  |  0.006 |
| DASHBTC | BUY  |  0.002 |
| LTCBTC  | BUY  |   0.02 |
| ETHBTC  | SELL |  0.026 |
| ETHBTC  | SELL |  0.004 |
| BCCBTC  | SELL |  0.005 |
| XRPBTC  | SELL |     14 |
+---------+------+--------+
```

which is information about coin pairs that I have bought or sold until today. I want to find an exact number of coins I am holding for each pair.

So basically I want the following response:

```
+---------+------+----------------------+
| market  | type | sum(amount)          |
+---------+------+----------------------+
| ADABTC  | BUY  |                   13 |
| BCCBTC  | BUY  |        0.00400000019 |
| DASHBTC | BUY  | 0.006000000284984708 |
| ETHBTC  | BUY  |         -0.098999999 |
| IOTABTC | BUY  |                    2 |
| LTCBTC  | BUY  |         0.0599999949 |
| XMRBTC  | BUY  |  0.01500000013038516 |
| XRPBTC  | BUY  |                    8 |
+---------+------+----------------------+
```

Can someone help me with the query for same?

Thanks

Comment: What is the logic for the transformation?

Comment: What have you tried? Seriously, that smells like homework and you haven't shown the least bit of effort to do it yourself.

Comment: `SELECT ..... SUM(amount) ... WHERE type = 'BUY' GROUP BY market, type`  should do the trick

Comment: How come you have a sum(amount) value lesser than 0 ? (ETHBTC)

Comment: actually, I am doing a small project and there I needed it since I was having difficulty in figuring out the query. it's highly judgemental @UlrichEckhardt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess simple `CASE` and `GROUP BY` should work

```
select market,
       sum(case when type = 'sell' then -amount
                when type = 'buy' then amount end)
from data
group by market
```

Comment: seems to work for whole numbers, but take DASHBTC as example. Its 0.002+0.002+0.002 = 0.006000000284984708

Comment: Thanks, @Radim. It helped